# Disable pCloud mounted drive

Tags: pcloud

When my system boots [pCloud](https://www.pcloud.com/) mounts a drive which adds an icon on my desktop and show the safely remove hardware icon in the top title bar.

As there's no option to stop this in the GUI is there something I can do system-wise i.e. I tried to add

```
umount /home/user/pCloudDrive
rm -rf /home/user/pCloudDrive
```

to my `rc.local` but the drive is not mounted at that time and fails. Also the folder won't delete for some reason.

Comment: What has pCloud Support https://www.pcloud.com/company/contactus.html told you?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1315199/change-default-mount-point-of-pcloud